# How to build EAR subproject and deploy it with Jenkins?

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins

My Maven project has a bunch of subprojects like this:

```
proj/
  projEAR/
  projCommon/
```

How can I compile and build the EAR project + deploy it to my web server at the same time?

The way I do it now is:

```
proj$ mvn clean install
[... builds everything ... ]
proj$ cd projEAR
projEAR$ mvn weblogic:deploy
[... deploys the EAR file ... ]
```

I'd like to do this with one command. Something like

```
proj$ mvn clean install projEAR/pom.xml weblogic:deploy
```

This fails of course, but I hope you get the idea...

**Update:**
The reason for all this is that jenkins only accepts one pom-file and command. So the problem is really how to configure Jenkins to run Maven twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work with Maven. But the way I solved it (in Jenkins) was

1. Create a *pre-build step* in Jenkins with the command `mvn clean install` using the parent pom: proj/pom.xml
2. Configure the main build as `weblogic:deploy` using projEAR/pom.xml.

This results in two commands being run: First `mvn clean install` followed by `mvn weblogic:deploy`.

Comment: As I said in my workaround, it would be more logic to create a post-build step for deploying, but it's fine if it's achieving the job.

Answer (score 3):

How about the weblogic-deployer-plugin of Jenkins. It will deploy your ear file to a weblogic instance. See [**WebLogic Deployer Plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WebLogic+Deployer+Plugin).

Answer (score 1):

### Quick and easy workaround

As a workaround, I can advise you to use some Jenkin's Plugins, like ["M2 Extra Steps"](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Extra+Steps+Plugin). It allow you to perform extra actions pre or post one. They are often use after a build to perform stuff like generating doc, or deploying something.

I know this is working well ... because I often use this trick :)

### Suggestion, never tried

At this moment, I don't have a straight answer. I don't really know how to do it in only one maven command. What I would try is to attach weblogic deploy phase to install.

***ear submodule*** --> pom.xml

```xml
<build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
        [...]

        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
           <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.9.1</version>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <configuration>
                    [...]
               </configuration>
               <goals>
                 <goal>install</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>
     [...]
    <plugins>        
    [...]
<build>
```

It should work, but once again, I never tried it.

Don't hesitate to give feed back

Comment: Looks like the way to go, I think you should link execution to a phase to so that it gets executed at the right moment: <phase>package</phase>

Comment: You're right, package would be a better phase than install. I was focused on the given command, but package would probably better suited for that.

Comment: I haven't tried your approach, but did it in Jenkins instead. But I'm sure your idea works as well.